# Why I need to create the same map if it was already created in Automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using Automapper 4.1.1 because of .NET Framework 4.0 needs to be. I decided to call Automapper configuration once per application starts. So, my classes look like:

```
// AutoMapper Business Logic Layer Configuration

public class PersonProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonDTO>().ReverseMap();
    }
}

public class PhotoProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Photo, PhotoDTO>().ReverseMap();
    }
}

public class DicProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Dic, DicDTO>().ReverseMap();
    }
}

public class SubjectProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Subject, SubjectDTO>().ReverseMap();
    }
}

public class PhotoSubjectIgnoreProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonDTO>()
              .ForMember(ph => ph.Photos, opt => opt.Ignore())
              .ForMember(sub => sub.Subjects, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }
}

public class PhotoSubjectIncludeProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonDTO>()
              .ForMember(pe => pe.Photos, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Photos))
              .ForMember(dto => dto.Subjects, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Subjects));
    }
}

// AutoMapper Presentation Layer Configuration

public class PersonViewProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<PersonDTO, PersonViewModel>()
              .ForMember(model => model.Photos, opt => opt.MapFrom(dto => dto.Photos))
              .ForMember(model => model.Subjects, opt => opt.MapFrom(dto => dto.Subjects))
              .ForMember(model => model.BirthdaySingle, opt => opt.MapFrom(dto => dto.BirthdaySingle.NullIntToNullDateTime("yyyyMMdd")));
        Mapper.CreateMap<PersonViewModel, PersonDTO>()
              .ForMember(dto => dto.Photos, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model.Photos))
              .ForMember(dto => dto.Subjects, opt => opt.MapFrom(dto => dto.Subjects))
              .ForMember(dto => dto.BirthdaySingle, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model.BirthdaySingle.NullDateTimeToNullInt("yyyyMMdd")));
    }
}

public class PersonShortViewProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<PersonDTO, PersonListViewModel.PersonShortViewModel>()
            .IgnoreAllNonExisting().ForMember(model => model.Birthday,opt => opt.MapFrom(dto => dto.BirthdaySingle.NullIntToNullDateTime("yyyyMMdd")));
    }
}
public class PhotoViewProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<PhotoDTO, PhotoViewModel>().ReverseMap();
    }
}

public class DicViewProfile:Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<DicDTO, DicViewModel>().ForSourceMember(dto => dto.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());
        Mapper.CreateMap<DicViewModel, DicDTO>().ForMember(dto => dto.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }
}

public class SubjectViewProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<SubjectDTO, SubjectViewModel>().ForSourceMember(dto => dto.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());
        Mapper.CreateMap<SubjectViewModel, SubjectDTO>().ForMember(dto => dto.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }
}
```

And class that collects profiles in whole application:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(configuration =>
                          GetConfiguration(Mapper.Configuration)
            );
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }

    private static void GetConfiguration(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        // Interesting thing: we need to use order by because we need photo mapping to be before Person mappings
        var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        var allTypes = assemblies.SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetExportedTypes());
        var profiles = allTypes.Where(type => typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom(type) && !type.IsAbstract && type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Profile))).ToArray();

        foreach (var profile in profiles)
        {
            configuration.AddProfile(Activator.CreateInstance(profile) as Profile);
        }
    }
}
```

I call main function in `Program.cs` class:

```
internal static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Главная точка входа для приложения.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
        // ...
    }
}
```

So, I have a method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get elements of type PersonDTO using paging settings
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pageNumber">Page number to get</param>
/// <param name="pageSize">Rows per page</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public IQueryable<PersonDTO> GetPersons(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{
    if (pageNumber < 1)
    {
        throw new ValidationException("Початкове значення має бути більше 0.", "");
    }
    if (pageSize < 1)
    {
        throw new ValidationException("Кількість записів має бути більше 0.", "");
    }
    PageInfo.TotalItems = Database.Persons.CountAll();
    PageInfo.CurrentPage = pageNumber;
    PageInfo.PageSize = pageSize;

    // применяем автомаппер для проекции одной коллекции на другую
    /*Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonDTO>()
            .ForMember(ph => ph.Photos, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(sub => sub.Subjects, opt => opt.Ignore());*/
    return Database.Persons.GetAll((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize, pageSize).ProjectTo<PersonDTO>();
}
```

And I get this error:

```
Message:
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source

ParamName:
    source
Source:
    System.Core
StackTrace:
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Select[TSource,TResult](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 selector)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Person )
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`3.<CombineSelectors>b__0(TSource x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.GetListFromEnumerable(IEnumerable enumerable)
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.ResetList()
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.set_DataSource(Object value)
   at Reestr.WinForms.Views.FrmMain.BindGrid(Int32 pageIndex, Expression`1 predicate) in B:\Programming\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Reestr_2\Reestr.WinForms\Views\FrmMain.cs:line 270
TargetSite:
    {System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TResult] Select[TSource,TResult](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TSource], System.Func`2[TSource,TResult])}
InnerException: null
```

But! If I uncomment `Mapper.CreateMap` row this error disappeares and everything works fine. Can't understand why it is so, because I've already created this Map in `PhotoSubjectIgnoreProfile` class.
Same situation with method:

```
public PersonDTO GetPerson(long id)
{
    var person = Database.Persons.GetById(id);
    if (person == null)
    {
        throw new ValidationException("Об'єкт не знайдено.", "");
    }
    // применяем автомаппер для проекции Person на PersonDTO
    /*Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonDTO>()
        .ForMember(pe => pe.Photos, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Photos))
        .ForMember(pe => pe.Subjects, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Subjects));*/
    return Mapper.Map<PersonDTO>(person);
}
```

This Map also have been created in `PhotoSubjectIncludeProfile` class...
How could I solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: There can only be one `Person, PersonDTO` mapping in the static AutoMapper API (the only one there is in 4.4.1), so it doesn't make sense to add the mapping more than once. The last wins and your code leaves it to reflection which is the last. If you want different mapping behavior you should use other DTO classes, inconvenient though it is.

Comment: @GertArnold I also thought about this behaviour. So, what is the reason then to use Profile instead of calling simple method?

Comment: That's just a matter of preference. With profiles you can bundle your mappings in logical groups.

Answer (score 1):

All of your profiles are incorrect. You need to call CreateMap on your Profile, not Mapper.CreateMap:

```
public class PersonProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<Person, PersonDTO>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've corrected my code according to your answer but it doesn't help to solve the error =( Is it really the problem in mapping same types only once per application?